# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/detail

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error,NoReverseMatch at /accounts/detail
Reverse for 'upload' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'accounts/upload/(?P\d+)/$']  .
I wrote in detail.html like

```
<body>
   <a href="{% url 'accounts:upload' %}"><img src="{% static 'accounts/Send.jpg' %}" alt="SEND"></a>
</body>
```

My ideal system is when I click images, it sends to upload method(maybe I should say photo.html).
I wrote in views.py like

```
def detail(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/detail.html')

def upload(request, p_id):
    form = UserImageForm(request.POST or None)
    d = {
        'p_id': p_id,
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', d)
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^detail$', views.detail,name='detail'),
    url(r'^photo/$', views.photo, name='photo'),
    url(r'^upload/(?P<p_id>\d+)/$', views.upload, name='upload'),
]
```

When I access http://localhost:8000/accounts/detail, these error happens.How can I fix this?What should I write it?

Comment: you need to pass `p_id` to your url in the template

Answer (score 2):

In your `urls.py`, your upload url expects the parameter `p_id`:

```
url(r'^upload/(?P<p_id>\d+)/$', views.upload, name='upload')
#                 ^^^
```

Therefore, when accessing this url in reverse, you must specifiy a value for `p_id`:

```
your_url = reverse('accounts:upload', p_id=123)
```

Or, in your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'accounts:upload' 123 %}">Click me</a>
```